# Jquery folder structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visual-studio, datatables

I have a fairly large web app and am using JQuery with JQuery UI, a couple JQuery plugins, a couple other javascript widgets.  And DataTables.  These pieces have been piling on throughout development and what I now have is a substantial mess of files and folders.  Some are duped, some I cannot tell if they belong at at all, but the biggest problem seems that some of these pieces rely of certain assets and folders having specific relative paths to one another.

So my question:  What is a folder/file structure that will work.  DataTables in particular seems most picky and easily breaks when I move stuff around.  I expected to be able to find this in the JQuery docs, and if not that then via some googling, but neither have panned out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i would try to narrow down the earliest version of jQuery needed to run your plugins and things, then use that version of jQuery throughout the entire application. I would include Google CDN-hosted version of jQuery in all of the instances it is included.

Comment: You do not have a common JS, CSS, and image folders in your project?

Comment: This sounds more like a file management problem than a jQuery one.

Answer (score 1):

With big JS applications, I would recommend using JS MVC framework like backbone: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Comment: thanks for the lead.  I'm only looking to organize our existing assets though, and would avoid writing (or rewriting) any browser code if possible.